# Postgresql Combine two select statement with different number of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

table1:

**tconst attr_a attr_b attr_c**

table2:

**tconst attr_d attr_e**

What I want:

**tconst attr_a attr_b attr_c attr_d attr_e**

Note:
The tconst in table1 and table2 are different numbers, no intersection

Could anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, so that both statements in the `union` have the same number of columns:

```
select tconst , attr_a , attr_b , attr_c, null attr_d, null attr_e
from table1

union all

select tconst , null attr_a , null attr_b , null attr_c, attr_d, attr_e
from table2
```